# Calculate the sum of even Fibonacci numbers

Tags: python, fibonacci-sequence

This is [my solution](https://github.com/AmirMotefaker/ProjectEuler/blob/main/Problem2.py) for [problem 2 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) using Python:

```
a, b = 1, 1
total = 0
while a <= 4000000:
    if a % 2 == 0:
        total += a
    a, b = b, a+b  # the real formula for Fibonacci sequence
print (total)
```

I put the codes in the **function** IsEven:

```
def IsEven(n):
     if n % 2 == 0:
         return True
     else:
         return False
```

Comment: Did you take a good look at the feedback on your previous question?

Comment: @Mast - Yes. I took a good look at the feedback on my previous question.
Is there a problem I did not fix?

Comment: The question still is not self-contained; please [edit] to add a short summary of the problem statement.  You can keep the link as a reference, but your question does need to be complete even if the linked material isn't accessible.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked  at other reviews of code solving this problem?  Some of them even appear in the "Related" sidebar, normally on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Modularity

We have the printing and the constraints (the constant `4000000`) mixed in with the logic of the code.  If we create a function, we can unit-test it, and we can time its execution (both of which will be useful to you if you attempt other Project Euler challenges).  Perhaps something like

```
def sum_even_fibonacci(limit)
    '''Return the sum of all even Fibonacci numbers
       not greater than LIMIT
    '''
    a, b = 1, 1
    total = 0
    while a <= limit:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            total += a
        a, b = b, a+b
    return total
```

## Simplify

The function that's unused is very long winded.  Any time we write `if condition: return True; else: return False`, we could simply write `return condition`.  I.e.

```
def IsEven(n):
     return n % 2 == 0
```

## Algorithm

Instead of generating all the Fibonacci numbers, use your mathematical knowledge to generate just the even ones.  Can you work out a formula for their sum?

Comment: I think "not greater than 'limit'" would be  more appropriate in the comments "not greater than LIMIT", because name in python are case sensitive

Comment: I'm not really sure of conventions for Python doc-comments, but upcasing the argument names in Emacs Lisp documentation doesn't seem to cause any confusion there, and I find it does help users to quickly find where each argument is used.